# Visual Basic and Mysql in phpMyadmin

Tags: mysql, sql, vb.net

I have created 3 text boxes and a picture box in visual basic. I am trying to retrieve data from my database. I have successfully retrieved the data through query output in the three text boxes.

The problem is I also have an image column in my database of type BLOB. How do I retrieve this image into my picture box.
I am not using an adapter. I just want the reader to load the image

The code in Visual Basic is:

```vb
Imports MySql.Data.MySqlClient


Public Class Form1
    Dim MysqlConn As MySqlConnection
    Dim COMMAND As MySqlCommand


    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        MysqlConn = New MySqlConnection
        MysqlConn.ConnectionString =
            "server=localhost;userid=root;password=;database=Birds"
        Try
            MysqlConn.Open()
            MessageBox.Show("Connection Established Successfully!")
            MysqlConn.Close()
        Catch ex As MySqlException
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
        Finally
            MysqlConn.Dispose()



        End Try
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        MysqlConn = New MySqlConnection
        MysqlConn.ConnectionString =
        "server=localhost;userid=root;password=;database=Birds"
        Dim READER As MySqlDataReader

        Try
            MysqlConn.Open()
            Dim Query As String

            Query = "select identification,descriptionNumber1,descriptionNumber2,image from Birds.BlackBirds where name='" & TextBox1.Text & "' "
            COMMAND = New MySqlCommand(Query, MysqlConn)
            READER = COMMAND.ExecuteReader


            READER.Read()
            TextBox4.Text = READER.GetString(0)
            TextBox2.Text = READER.GetString(1)
            TextBox3.Text = READER.GetString(2)


            'What do I do here ???
            PictureBox1.Image = READER.GetByte(3)

            READER.Close()

            MysqlConn.Close()

        Catch ex As MySqlException
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
        Finally
            MysqlConn.Dispose()

        End Try
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Please read [Ask] and also take the [Tour].  I removed all the irrelevant and meaningless  emtpy event handlers for you

Comment: Also it will be useful for you to start with a search about _retrieving images from a database_ This problem has been asked and answered a lot of times

Comment: You generally do the reverse of what you did to add it to the DB.  In this case convert the bytes back to an image

Comment: This code is crazy vulnerable to sql injection attacks. It's practically begging to get hacked.